# How do I keep formatting when copying from gedit into open office?

Tags: formatting, copy, openoffice.org, paste, gedit

I am editing octave files in gedit, and it does a nice job highlighting them. However, when I try to copy and paste the code into Open Office, it loses all formatting. Even when I try paste > special, it still doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this without having to manually go through all my code highlighting keywords?

Comment: I know Scite has a "Copy as RTF" option, but I have no idea for gedit.

Comment: You want something like GNU Source-Highlight.  Unfortunately, this does not seem to support Octave/Matlab.

Comment: Try [hilite.me](http://hilite.me/).

Answer (score 3):

The free and open source editor **KATE** can actually **export in HTML** Octave's code keeping the correct syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found this very usefull page: http://tohtml.com/
So you don't need to install any other editor or stuff, just copy paste to the page and let it do it.

PS: It seems like the owner likes to sell the domain, so hopefully the project will stay online, otherwise you will find other solutions google: "cpp online syntaxhighlighter"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be any good, but if you open the script with the Matlab® editor, then you can make copy and paste (paste > special), keeping the Octave syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install KDE dependencies for run Kate I found a solution that could work until Scite implementation in GNU/Linux (?) haven't got the command "Copy as RTF", take a look [here](http://www.scintilla.org/CommandValues.html)

So let's go:

```
sudo apt-get install wine synapse
```

wine: Windows Emulator ;)

synapse: fast application launcher

download [notepad++](http://notepadplusplus.org/) installer version

go to Downloads, `chmod +x` executable file (permissions to execute, could do graphically with properties of file, in permissions)

install it! (with default values works)

now you can run it easily with synapse:
if is launched: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (or <kbd>Super</kbd> (windows key)+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and type "notepad" (if no appear, press Arrow Down and search it!)

write a text in, for example:

```
for i=1:3
  %comment!
end
```

and now select it, with right button of mouse "plugin commands > copy text with syntax highlighting"

paste it!

in LibreOffice Writer: be carefull, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or Edit>Paste Especial>Formated Text [RTF]

in Abiword works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>